# How to remove Spire.XLS signature from pdf File?

Tags: java, excel, digital-signature, spire.xls

I'm working on java, i have an excel file named "file.xlsx" that i want to convert to pdf using Spire.XLS , this is the code i wrote for that :

```
            //Create a Workbook instance
            workbook = new Workbook();
            //Load an Excel file
            workbook.loadFromFile("file.xlsx");

            //Get the first worksheet
            sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
            //Add a new worksheet to the workbook
            sheet_copy = workbook.getWorksheets().add("Copy of sheet1");
            //Copy the first worksheet to the new worksheet
            sheet_copy.copyFrom(sheet);

            //Save the result file
            workbook.saveToFile("file.xlsx");
            
            workbook.saveToFile("result.pdf", com.spire.xls.FileFormat.PDF);
```

The pdf file is generated but with a signature : ***Evaluation Warning : The document was created with Spire.XLS for Java*** , i'm wondering about how to remove it , any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Request a pro Trial License OR

Per the age old answer use the free version

> Free version doesn't have evaluation warning on result file.
> Please make sure the version you were using is correct,

https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/evaluation-warning-the-document-was-created-with-spire-pdf-t4925.html

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/xls-for-java-free.html

or for .net users

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-free.html